# Telegram unable to import the contacts in node js

Tags: node.js, telegram, tdlib

Importing the excel with phone numbers and tried to send the same message to all the numbers. I'm using the "tdlib" for telegram API in node js. node version 10.16. I'm getting the below error always

```
[ 2][t 4][1562735989.296543121][ConnectionCreator.cpp:992][#1][!ConnectionCreator]  [[2001:b28:f23f:f005::a]:443] to DcId{5}: [PosixError : No route to host : 65 : Failed to connect to [[2001:b28:f23f:f005::a]:443]]

    { _: 'error',
      code: 429,
      message: 'Too Many Requests: retry after 295' }
```

Here is my code

```
const telegramConnect = async () => {
    const { Client } = require('tdl');
    const { TDLib } = require('tdl-tdlib-ffi');

    const number = '+9196xxxxxx43';
    const telegramClient = new Client(new TDLib(), {
        number,
        apiId: 86xxx5, // Your api_id
        apiHash: '27xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc7b1', // Your api_hash
    });

    telegramClient.on('Telegram Connection Error ', console.error);

    await telegramClient.connectAndLogin();

    return telegramClient;
}
```

In node js im calling the above function

```
 client = await telegramConnect();
    contacts = [
    {
        _: 'contact',
        phone_number: '+9196xxxxxx36',
        first_name: 'Jegan',
        last_name: '',
        vcard: '',
        user_id: 0
    },
    {
        _: 'contact',
        phone_number: '+9198xxxxxx10',
        first_name: 'mob12',
        last_name: 'mob12',
        vcard: '',
        user_id: 0
    }
];

const importContact = await client.invoke({
                _: 'importContacts',
                contacts: contacts
            });
```

After this method, I'm trying to send the message. My code execution was stopped here. Help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you figured out the issue? Would you like to share the solution?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue using the python's version http://python-telegram.readthedocs.io/. It seems that you exceeded your request per time limit. In our case we're waiting this "retry after x seconds" to proceed.